# Animating Background Image based on Picker value SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have a fairly simple view with a background image and a picker. I would like to change the background image based on the currently selected value. The code below works, but the animation for the image change is missing - any idea why?

```
@State private var pickerIndex = 0
@State private var currentBackgroundImage = "fitness-1"

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(currentBackgroundImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .transition(.opacity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    
                    Picker(selection: $pickerIndex, label: Text("")) {
                        Image("img1")
                            .tag(0)
                        Image("img2")
                            .tag(1)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: genderPickerIndex, perform: { value in
                        if(value == 0) {
                            withAnimation {
                                currentBackgroundImage = "fitness-1"
                            }
                        } else {
                            withAnimation {
                                currentBackgroundImage = "fitness-2"
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .frame(width: 100)
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

It seems like it has nothing to do with the Picker - I just replaced it with a button and the image change is still not animated. Am I missing some modifier on the image?

```
ZStack {
    Image(currentBackgroundImage)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .transition(.opacity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
           
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation {
            currentBackgroundImage = "fitness-2"
        }
    }) {
        Text("Change Image")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting withAnimation inside onChange .

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so to get the animation I wanted, I ended up creating an extra component:

```
struct ImageSwitcher: View {
    
    let firstImage: String
    let secondImage: String
    
    @Binding var firstImageShowing: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(firstImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .opacity(firstImageShowing ? 1 : 0)
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.17))
                .isHidden(!firstImageShowing)
               
            Image(secondImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .opacity(firstImageShowing ? 0 : 1)
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .isHidden(firstImageShowing)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.17))
        }
    }
}
```

the .isHidden modifier is an extension to hide the image based on a state variable. You can see more details in this post: [Dynamically hiding view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490250/dynamically-hiding-view-in-swiftui)

You can obviously modify the transition, but I ended up going with both move and a fade in/out using the transition and opacity modifier.

USAGE:

Create a state variable:

```
@State private var showFirst = true
```

Then give it to the component along with your image names:

```
ImageSwitcher(firstImage: "img-1", secondImage: "img-2", firstImageShowing: $showFirst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Picker selection is of type `String`, and your picker data is of type `Text`, so your `onChange` modifier isn’t invoked. Picker selection type and `content` type must be same, also explained by @Asperi in link [Picker in SwiftUI works with one version of ForEach, but not the other - a bug, or expected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938232/picker-in-swiftui-works-with-one-version-of-foreach-but-not-the-other-a-bug). Instead you could use `forEach` and loop over your `[string]` names.

```
struct ContentViewsss:View{
    var images = ["ABC","CDF"]
    @State private var pickerValue = "ABC"
    @State private var currentBackgroundImage = "ABC"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(currentBackgroundImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .transition(.opacity)
            
            Picker(selection: $pickerValue, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(images,id:\.self) { imageName in
                    Text("\(imageName)")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: pickerValue, perform: { value in
                
                self.changeBackgroundImage(value)
            })
            .frame(width: 200)
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
        }
    }
    
    func changeBackgroundImage(_ value: String) {
        switch value {
        case "ABC":
            withAnimation {
                currentBackgroundImage = "ABC"
            }//the app changes the image, but the "withAnimation" does not seem to do anything
        
        case "CDF":
            withAnimation {
                currentBackgroundImage = "CDF"
            }//the app changes the image, but the "withAnimation" does not seem to do anything
        
        default:
            currentBackgroundImage = "landing-page"
        }
        
    }
}
```

Or you could directly assign `newValue` inside `onChange`, instead of separate function.

```
struct ContentViewsss:View{
    var images = ["ABC","CDF"]
    @State private var pickerValue = "ABC"
    @State private var currentBackgroundImage = "ABC"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(currentBackgroundImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .transition(.opacity)
            
            Picker(selection: $pickerValue, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(images,id:\.self) { imageName in
                    Text("\(imageName)")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: pickerValue, perform: { value in
           withAnimation {
                currentBackgroundImage = value
             } 
                //self.changeBackgroundImage(value)
            })
            .frame(width: 200)
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my code I already had it with the ForEach.. I tried to make it simpler in StackOverflow and messed up the code. Sorry that's my bad!

I now tried to assign the new value directly in the onChange. Again the image changes, but **without an animation**. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tobilence is the issue fixed? I can see animation happening in my code.I just added withAnimation block as well in onChange.

Comment: No in my code it still does not work - give me a few minutes I'll update my post with my current code.

Comment: I edited it - I now use an index instead of the String value in the picker, but no animation is happening

Comment: @Tobilence what is genderPickerIndex? I changed it to pickerIndex and it’s working fine.

Comment: That was a copy paste error. I changed it too, but it still doesn't work.. Guess I'll have to debug some more

Comment: It seems like it has nothing to do with the picker after all - I just updated it with a button instead and still no animation